# Why does my blower fan sound like a yeti?

Tags: hvac

My A/C inside my house is making some kind of strange grinding noise. The fan wants to start, it blows cold air, and attempts to come on but only until whatever is making it drag stops the wheel fan thing and shuts the button inside the closet off. We have removed the filter to check it out, it definitely sounds and looks to be coming directly from the blower fan. (I think that's what it's called) Although the filter was due for a change and there is some dirt that accumulated, we regularly keep ours clean so it's not from that. It spins well when we remove it out of the unit but sticks and grinds and drags when we place it back in. There is no visible damage. Please help!!

Comment: The yetis in my area are extremely loud and annoying.  If yours are anything like mine, I can certainly empathize with you here.

Comment: I'm confused by this sentence "*It spins well when we remove it out of the unit but sticks and grinds and drags when we place it back in.*"  Are you removing the blower motor/fan, or the filter? Do you mean "*The fan spins well when we remove the filter, but sticks, grinds, and drags when we place the filter back in.*"?

Comment: @oscilatingcretin  So THAT's what you're keeping in your soundproof room!!!

Answer (score 1):

If the blower fan assembly turns freely when when it is removed from the forced air unit then there must be either something that is adjacent to where the blower mounts that has gotten in there. When the blower is out check very carefully for anything that may be in there. Maybe there is a flap, piece of insulation or even a dead animal that got into that area.

From the description given it was not fully clear, but it sounds like the blower fan is directly mounted to the motor shaft as opposed to there being some type of drive belt assembly between the blower and the motor. It is possible that there may be an internal failure inside the motor that is causing the problem. Normally you would be able to detect that when manually turing the motor - but not always. If there is a separation between the two then you would need to check both ends of the unit - motor and blower - plus the belt.